# Java application with azure service bus

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I have an audit service. other application will call that service for auditing purpose. my concern is all call to audit service to be queued in azure service bus to make sure fault tolerance.please help me with how to queue other service call to audit service.

Comment: Hi,any updates ? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: If you think my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you already have considered using service bus, there is no concern about fault tolerance. That's the exactly feature of Azure Service Bus.

Let the other services send message to the queues and your audit service receive those messages to consume them in the order.

You could create queues using the Azure portal, PowerShell, CLI, or Resource Manager templates. You then send and receive messages using a [QueueClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient) object.

To quickly learn how to create a queue, then send and receive messages to and from the queue, see the [quickstarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal) for each method. For a more in-depth tutorial on how to use queues, see [Get started with Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

For a working sample, see the [BasicSendReceiveUsingQueueClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSendReceiveUsingQueueClient) sample on GitHub.

Then if you concern fault tolerance about audit service,you could use `ReceiveAndDelete` mode. `ReceiveAndDelete` mode is the simplest model and works best for scenarios in which the application can tolerate not processing a message if a failure occurs.More details, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#receive-modes).